# Pandas - Rolling window - CustomIndex - right bound is not included in window for sum

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I am discovering the CustomIndexer and I can see the 'end' (left bound) is not included in the subsequent sum I would like to do.

It leads to 2 problems:

- sum is not achieved on the rows I want it
- 1st row of the DataFrame cannot be managed properly (because, instead of a window with a single cell, the window is an empty window)

To solve the 1st consequence, I resorted to include the next row to make sure window ends where I want it to end.

But then, I have no fall back for the second problem.

### The original code

So I tested 1st my custom window in a separate function to ease debugging.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def custom_bounds(num_values, index, date_range):
    start = np.empty(num_values, dtype=np.int64)
    end = np.empty(num_values, dtype=np.int64)        
    ind_as_int = index.to_series().reset_index(drop=True) 
    dr_as_series = date_range.to_series()
    # 1st item is skipped and default to 0
    start[0]=0
   end[0]=0
    # Loop for other items
    for i in range(num_values)[1:]:
        previous_ts_in_dr = dr_as_series.loc[dr_as_series.index < ind_as_int.iat[i]].index[-1]
        start[i] = ind_as_int.loc[ind_as_int >= previous_ts_in_dr].index[0]
        end[i] = i-1
return start, end
```

### Input data as example

I could test it with following input values.

```
from random import seed
from random import randint

# DataFrame
ts_1h = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01 00:00+00:00', end='2020-01-02 00:00+00:00', freq='1h')
seed(1)
values = [randint(0,10) for ts in ts_1h]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Values' : values}, index=ts_1h)
df.index.name='Timestamp'

# Processing
dr = pd.date_range(start='2019-12-31 23:00+00:00', end='2020-01-03 00:00+00:00', freq='3h')
```

Running it:

```
In [20]: df.head(4)
Out[20]: 
                           Values
Timestamp                                   
2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00       2
2020-01-01 01:00:00+00:00       9
2020-01-01 02:00:00+00:00       1
2020-01-01 03:00:00+00:00       4
```

## Running the original code with input data

```
start, end = custom_bounds(num_values=df.shape[0], index=df.index, date_range=dr)

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'int' : df.reset_index().index,
                 'start' : start,
                 'end' : end},
                index = df.index)
df_2.loc[df_2.index.isin(dr), 'TS_3h'] = 'X'
```

So basically, in df_2, we can see integers marking the start and end of custom windows. Both of these bounds have to be included in the rolliwng window. I am fine with the values you can read.

```
In [22]: df_2.head(6)
Out[22]: 
                           int  start  end TS_3h
Timestamp                                       
2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00    0      0    0   NaN
2020-01-01 01:00:00+00:00    1      0    0   NaN
2020-01-01 02:00:00+00:00    2      0    1     X
2020-01-01 03:00:00+00:00    3      2    2   NaN
2020-01-01 04:00:00+00:00    4      2    3   NaN
2020-01-01 05:00:00+00:00    5      2    4     X
```

So I am confident with the next step. I intend to see the following sum:

- for row 1 (int 0), its actual values: 2
- for row 2 (int 1), value of row 1: 2
- for row 3 (int 2), sum of values from rows 1 & 2: 11

## Implementing CustomIndexer & running it

So I integrated my code in a custom 'get_window_bounds()' as follow.

```
from pandas.api.indexers import BaseIndexer


class CustomIndexer(BaseIndexer):

    def get_window_bounds(self, num_values, min_periods, center, closed):
        start = np.empty(num_values, dtype=np.int64)
        end = np.empty(num_values, dtype=np.int64)        
        ind_as_int = self.index.to_series().reset_index(drop=True) 
        dr_as_series = self.date_range.to_series()
        # 1st item is skipped and default to 0
        start[0]=0
        end[0]=0
        # Loop for other items
        for i in range(num_values)[1:]:
            previous_ts_in_dr = dr_as_series.loc[dr_as_series.index < ind_as_int.iat[i]].index[-1]
            start[i] = ind_as_int.loc[ind_as_int >= previous_ts_in_dr].index[0]
            end[i] = i-1
        return start, end

indexer = CustomIndexer(index=df.index, date_range=dr, closed='both')
df['Sum'] = df.rolling(indexer).sum()
df.loc[df.index.isin(dr), 'TS_3h'] = 'X'
```

Running it:

```
In [25]: df.head(4)
Out[25]: 
                           Values  Sum TS_3h
Timestamp                                   
2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00       2  0.0   NaN
2020-01-01 01:00:00+00:00       9  0.0   NaN
2020-01-01 02:00:00+00:00       1  2.0     X
2020-01-01 03:00:00+00:00       4  0.0   NaN
```

As said, I would intend to see following results:

- for row 1 (int 0), its actual values: 2
- for row 2 (int 1), value of row 1: 2
- for row 3 (int 2), sum of values from rows 1 & 2: 11

So question is: how can I make sure right bound is included in the computation for the sum?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved with meddling with the index. Sorry for disturbance.

```
    def get_window_bounds(self, num_values, min_periods, center, closed):
        start = np.empty(num_values, dtype=np.int64)
        end = np.empty(num_values, dtype=np.int64)        
        ind_as_int = self.index.to_series().reset_index(drop=True) 
        dr_as_series = self.date_range.to_series()
        # Loop over items
        for i in range(num_values):
            previous_ts_in_dr = dr_as_series.loc[dr_as_series.index < ind_as_int.iat[i]].index[-1]
            start[i] = ind_as_int.loc[ind_as_int >= previous_ts_in_dr].index[0]
            end[i] = i
        # Correct end[0]
        end[0]=1
        return start, end
```